# Typescript type generation issue in switch statement

Tags: typescript, types

I have this map function that is rendering the type of an object.

```
function mapStuffs(fields: any) {
    switch (fields.type) {
        case "NewStuffs":
            return {
                type: "NewStuffs" as const,
                stuff: fields.stuff
            };
        case "StuffFile":
            const fileName = "jadflkjs";
            const stuffId = "adlkajsf";
            return {
                type: "StuffFile" as const,
                fileName,
                stuffId
            };
        default:
            return {
                type: "ExistingStuff" as const
            };
    }
}
```

And when I build, the generated type is:

```
mainstuff:
        | {
              stuff: string | undefined;
              type: "NewStuffs";
              fileName?: undefined;
              stuffId?: undefined;
          }
        | {
              type: "StuffFile";
              fileName: string;
              stuffId: string;
          }
        | {
              type: "ExistingStuff";
              fileName?: undefined;
              stuffId?: undefined;
          };
```

I don't understand how to remove *fileName* and *stuffId* as optional parameters when they're not required. Is it a typescript bug?
What I would like to have is this type:

```
mainstuff:
        | {
              stuff: string | undefined;
              type: "NewStuffs";
          }
        | {
              type: "StuffFile";
              fileName: string;
              stuffId: string;
          }
        | {
              type: "ExistingStuff";
          };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a TypeScript bug.  This is the intended behavior since TypeScript 2.7 introduced [improved type inference for object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#improved-type-inference-for-object-literals).  The fact that `fileName` and `stuffId` is not being included for some of the return values makes the compiler think that absence should be reflected in the return type.

The type inference algorithm in TypeScript is a set of heuristics, where the language designers try to guess what kinds of things most people want to see in certain circumstances.  If you don't like the inferred type, you are free to [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) of your `mapStuffs()` function with whatever type you prefer, and the compiler will be happy with this, assuming your function implementation conforms to it:

```
type MappedStuff = {
    stuff: string | undefined;
    type: "NewStuffs";
} | {
    type: "StuffFile";
    fileName: string;
    stuffId: string;
} | {
    type: "ExistingStuff";
};

function mapStuffs(fields: any): MappedStuff {

    switch (fields.type) {
        case "NewStuffs":
            return {
                type: "NewStuffs" as const,
                stuff: fields.stuff
            };
        case "StuffFile":
            const fileName = "jadflkjs";
            const stuffId = "adlkajsf";
            return {
                type: "StuffFile" as const,
                fileName,
                stuffId
            };
        default:
            return {
                type: "ExistingStuff" as const
            };
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATAysArgM01AvFAbwCgpSoBnDbALguACcBLAOwHMoAfKdZpCTFhCQBuEmVCRaAIgByEAO5osmclNEBfToTGkJEaUuwAxRgBsIanVAHmZcALb66TNqLJ1lASSS1KL1hpaxO560gCiAB6MlCyshpiW6qJEmDwAxsCMAPbMUPYI8eQAFAIQpkjktHDMIACUtPCIQvHaVuTyjMBpABZQJYxlFQB0erXa7u5pcOTQsgqFUtRWE2T0EBj0ucErO7rgTnOKVCpSUNNQaTmUADTLu2SUyrSl5eRDj9h3K0lfF9Oz8RM5kWv0mV2A1jMEDsjjwUCkACs4EhMKYANYI1Rue6kS7MSgebDeOFSZHouCYhLYnFrDZbUE7ULwwFQ07nPE3BkrGzQhwQW44lYfTDeLlQH67PiYODoUzAJaCqC09CbcaK8T7cJRGJseJs8gXcFiiVkdREdRAA)

Comment: thanks a lot! now it's really clear! very helpful

Comment: but now my question is: why I don't see "stuff" attribute in the other objects?

Comment: Sorry, I’m not sure what you’re asking.  Follow up questions may deserve their own posts, in any case.

Comment: sure, sorry, I was just asking why the "issue" I had was happening only with 'fileName' and 'stuffId' (attributes for type="StuffFile") and not for 'stuff' (attribute for type="NewStuffs"). But no worries, I'll open a new question

Comment: I’m not sure because the question has `any` for `fields`, but also `string | undefined` for `fields.stuff` somehow.  I think I’ll need a true [mcve] before I can answer (also on mobile right now so I can’t check easily at the moment)

Comment: So, now that I got a chance to look from a real computer, [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/mq8XRN).  It looks like your example code does not actually exhibit the behavior you are asking about.  Please consider either modifying to a [mcve], preferably in a new post.  Good luck!

Comment: yes you reproduced the issue in the typescriptlang link! thanks anyway!